# Cross-Platform way to get CPU/Memory utilization

Tags: c++, c, windows, linux, macos

Looking for a library or a fairly cross platform method to get CPU utilization, memory utilization, etc in C/C++.  Something OTHER than getrusage(), I need for entire system, not one process.  I've checked around, but haven't found much.  I really need it on Linux, Mac Os X, and Windows, but if there's a solution for *nix systems (including OS X) but not Windows, I can work around that.

If all else fails, then ANY methods to do this on ANY of the above platforms would be good to know, and I can figure out how to package them myself!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [cross platform](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE-versions-i.html)  framework [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html) has a wrapper for [getrusage](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/Doxygen/Micro/ace/a01964.html#ab633890ce8dc4935e5317974e852a08) that should work on most if not all supported platforms.